# Add custom script to ScriptManager?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, scriptmanager

I love how in ASP.NET the ScriptManager has a composite section which allows one to specify multiple javascript files and it does the legwork of merging them all into one file at runtime.

I.E.

```
//input scriptB.js, scriptB.js
ScriptManager.CompositeScript.Scripts.Add("~/scriptA.js")//psuedo code
ScriptManager.CompositeScript.Scripts.Add("~/scriptB.js")//psuedo code
//output
scriptC.js
```

Is it possible to add javascript source directly to the scriptmanager, E.G.:

```
ScriptManager.CompositeScript.Scripts.Add("alert('hello');")//psuedo code
```

Answer (score 2):

You could add script through ScriptManager like this:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), ClientID,"alert('hello');", true);
```

This script will be added directly to page.

Comment: It doesnt merge it with the ScriptManager's almagamated js, so not quite the solution.

Comment: Yes it gonna marge script, if you add script whith same key, ClientID in my exapmle

Answer (score -1):

It works for me when I do it like this

```
Private Sub test()
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me.Page, Me.GetType(), "k1", "alert('hello')", True)
    End Sub
```

but when I add [SweerAlert](http://lipis.github.io/bootstrap-sweetalert/) to it it wont work

```
Private Sub test()
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me.Page, Me.GetType(), "k1", "swal('Please Provide All Valid Message Information!')", True)
        End Sub
```

do you have any idea why it dont works.

Comment: This is not an answer. it's another question. Please post it as a new question